# Solving an optimal control problem (LQR)

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, control-systems

Given a linear time-invariant system:

$$ \dot{x}(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t) $$

with 
initial state $ x(0)=x_0 $ and final state $ x(T)=x_T $.

The performance measure to be minimized is:

$$ \int_{0}^{T} ((x_T-x(t))^T(x_T-x(t))+u(t)^Tu(t) dt $$

$(x_T-x(t)) $ is the difference between the state of the system at time $ t $ and the final state. I want to compute an optimal control $ u^* $ that induces a transition  from the initial state $x_0 $ to the target state $x_T$. This is a LQR.

So if I let

$$ A=\begin{bmatrix} -1 & 0.5 \\ 0.3 & -1 \end{bmatrix},    B=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
and let the initial state be $ x_0=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} $  and the final state be $ x_T=\begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $.

What would be the optimal control trajectories in this specific case? I know there are some functions in mathematica for control theoretical application, but I have zero experience using them and just started to get deeper into this topic.

I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: There are no built-in functions for this. But you could setup the Hamiltonian and costate equations and use NDSolve to solve them.

Comment: $B$ is a $2$x$1$ matrix, and $u$ is a vector of length $1$.

Comment: @SubaThomas: Thanks for the hint, I really thought mathematica has some functions for that ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

my solution

```
A={{-1,0.5},{0.3,-1}}; B={{1},{1}};
x0={{1},{0}}; xT={{0},{1}};
```

You have to choose an end time

```
T=10;
```

Next you have to define the Hamilton function

[image]

```
L[t_]=1/2(u[t]^2)
lambda[t_]:={{l1[t]},{l2[t]}}
x[t_] := {{x1[t]}, {x2[t]}}
f[t_] = A.x[t] + B u[t]
H[t_] = Flatten[L[t] + lambda[t]\[Transpose].f[t]][[1]]
```

Then, according to the calculus of variations the following has to hold

[image]

```
uSol = First@Solve[0 == -D[H[t], u[t]], u[t]]
```

[image]

```
TableForm[eqn1=Table[D[lambda[t][[i,1]],t]==-D[H[t]/.uSol,x[t][[i,1]]],{i,1,2}]]
```

[image]

```
TableForm[
 eqn2 = Table[
   D[x[t][[i, 1]], t] == D[H[t] /. uSol, lambda[t][[i, 1]]], {i, 1, 
    2}]]
```

[image]

Now you have a boundary value problem. You just need boundary values

```
bc1 = Table[x[0][[i, 1]] == x0[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 2}]
bc2 = Table[x[T][[i, 1]] == xT[[i, 1]], {i, 1, 2}]
```

And you are ready to solve the bvp

```
sol = NDSolve[
  Flatten[{eqn1, eqn2, bc1, bc2}], {x1[t], x2[t], l1[t], l2[t]}, {t, 
   0, T}]
```

which gives the numerical solution functions, that you can plot.

```
Grid[{{Plot[{Evaluate[x1[t] /. sol], Evaluate[x2[t] /. sol]}, {t, 0, 
     T}, ImageSize -> Medium], 
   Plot[{Evaluate[x1[t] /. sol], Evaluate[x2[t] /. sol]}, {t, 0, T}, 
    PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}, ImageSize -> Medium]}}]
```

[image]

You can also verify the solution

```
sol /. t -> T
```

[image]

and plot the optimal control signal

```
Plot[{Evaluate[u[t] /. uSol /. sol]}, {t, 0, T}, ImageSize -> Medium]
```

[image]

As you can see the final state is almost exactly the requested. The control effort is dependent on the time T. All of the above would also work for nonlinear problems and with little effort for higher order systems.

**Edit:**

You could also define the Lagrange function as follows

```
L[t_] = 1/2 (x1[t]^2 + x2[t]^2 + u[t]^2)
```

This weighting off the states is not mandatory because the resulting weighting matrix Q just has to be positiv semi definit, so all zeros would be an option. By the way the above weighting corresponds to Q being a unity matrix. With this you get

[image]

As you can see the states deviate a little less from zero than before.

Comment: Thanks so much, that helped me understand how to work this problem in mathematica ! I'm confused about one thing though: 1. Shouldn't the Lagrange function be $ (x1[t]-x2[t])^2+u[t]^2 $ based on the cost function I specified above?

Comment: I don't think so the weighting off the final state can not be part of the integral, after all it only would be a scalar value and no time function. If you have a look at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator#Finite-horizon.2C_continuous-time_LQR you can see the weighting is done by the first part in front off the integral.

Comment: I see, thank you! Just wondering one more thing, shouldn't there be two optimal control signals $u_1(t) $ and $ u_2(t) $?

Comment: You have a single input system (the input matrix has one column) so no.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I got confused! Thanks again!

Comment: @OhmSweetOhm: I think the Lagrange function needs to be $(x[T]-x[t])^T (x[T]-x[t]) + u[t]^T u[t]$, while you had only the latter term, right? Because its the integrand of the term to be mini/maximized plus the $\lambda f$ term.

Comment: How to solve this task at an infinite time interval?